# Webview activity not showing anything on second load

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have this weird problem when showing an activity which consists (only) out of a webview.

The first time I start this Activity B by clicking on something in activity A, B is properly loaded and functional. I press the return button, go back to A, then click on the same button to go to B and my webview doesn't show anything. Debugged it tons of times and nothing seems out of the ordinary. There are also no crashes in the stack trace log... This problem by the wway occurs always in debug mode and only sometimes in run mode.

Here is the code for the activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin);
    myItem = (Item) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Item");
    initView();
    initHandlers();
}

private void initView()
{
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview_spin);
    //TODO : webViewClient vs webChromeClient ?
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(myItem);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/item.html?item="+json);
}

private void initHandlers()
{
    OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            webView.reload();
        }
    };
    orientationEventListener.enable();
}
```

FYI this problem occured before setting the orientationlistener.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like somehow the render process of the WebView is failing. You could store the WebViewClient you created on a variable and check the result of its method onRenderProcessGone() to check if it is rendering the second time you load the activity. Here you have all the WebViewClient methods: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient